# Can't send AT comands to ESP8266 on any baud rate

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, baud-rate

I have problem with baud rate. I have changed baud rate of esp from 115200 to 9600 with AT command AT+CIOBAUD. And everything worked fine until I wanted to change it back and executed command AT+CIOBAUD115200, after which everything I send trough arduino IDE serial monitor to ESP I get gibberish. I have tried all baud rated available in serial monitor but got nothing. Wiring stayed the same.

```
TX -> arduino RX
RX -> arduino TX
GND -> GND
CH_PD -> 3,3V
VCC -> 3,3V
```

I thought that if I can flash ESP firmware it will get back all default parameters, hence I tried flow these steps ([link](http://cordobo.com/2300-flash-esp8266-01-with-arduino-uno/)) but I stopped when executed `esptool.py --port /dev/ttyACM0 erase_flash` which got me

```
esptool.py v1.3
Connecting...................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet ('\x00')
```

In some forums is said that to get rid of error I need to change baud rate, but nothings works for me.

Please advise how can I fix this problem.

Comment: GPIO0 has to be connected to ground to enable programming mode.

Comment: Yes, during the flashing GPO0 was connected to ground.